# Batch Insert/Delete using slick?

Tags: postgresql, slick

I am new to Slick and I was wondering if people use it to perform a batch insert/delete using this framework or is it just used for queries and some other tool is recommended for big batch operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick can be used for batch insert and delete . You just build the seq with all of data you would like to insert and do db.run to do bulk insert . Similar applies for delete too .

Refer [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting) for more information .